# Accessing Json data in typescript

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api

I have a JSON object from the Facebook api that has all the posts from a public page. I am using type script to grab the object and assign it to a variable. But I can't figure out how to access the fields. How do you access JSON data in type script?

Here is my JSON file:
https://graph.facebook.com/1650393515218783?fields=posts&access_token=EAAN3TCkzCxsBACdSQIu3KDiORivp0eEeQWNMBu1aT8TnEWYEqQhblcl4IZAykwIwDFF5v6LB8BYNyOXYWrRhE7ildN2lnXFqwpnv7Bzq3Kh2ZB5FZBAMxrbpNEX2znds1G86AurOZAD0R1W3ec1ZBhwr8LNZAZCyGjgtMGbiZA44XwZDZD

Here is my function:

```
getBadger() {

    var link = 'https://graph.facebook.com/1650393515218783? fields=posts&access_token=EAAN3TCkzCxsBACdSQIu3KDiORivp0eEeQWNMBu1aT8TnEWYEqQhblcl4IZA$

    this.http.get(link).subscribe(data => { this.data = data; this.posts = JSON.parse(data._body); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.posts.data[0].message` will give you the message of the first story in the response you got back.

But you probably want to model the response using types other than `any`, in which case you can define the following:

```
interface FbApiResponse {
    posts: {
        id: string;
        data: FBResponseElement;
    }
}

interface FbResponseElement {
    message?: string;
    story?: string;
    created_time: string;
    id: string;
}
```

Though, I'm guessing this based on your data. I don't actually know what the API you're working with is, what its responses look like, or what they should be named.

You could then use a type assertion on your call to `JSON.parse`:

```
JSON.parse(data._body) as FbApiResponse
```